# Lazy loading module with children routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have receive an error trying to navigate to app/enter-transaction/product-select.

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'app/enter-transaction/product-selection'

Here is how I implement the routing.(include lazy loading module)

App.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LayoutComponent } from "./layout/layout.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "app",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "app",
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "enter-transaction",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import(
            "./modules/enter-transaction.module/enter-transaction.module"
          ).then(mod => mod.EnterTransactionModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

enter-transaction.module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { EnterTransactionRoutingModule } from "./enter- 
transaction.routing.model";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule, EnterTransactionRoutingModule]
})
export class EnterTransactionModule {}
```

enter-transcation-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { ProductSelectionComponent } from "./../../enter- 
transaction/product-selection/product-selection.component";
import { InvestorDetailComponent } from "./../../enter- 
transaction/investor-detail/investor-detail.component";
import { EnterTransactionComponent } from "src/app/enter- 
transaction/enter-transaction.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "enter-transaction",
    component: EnterTransactionComponent,
    children: [
       {
        path: "product-selection",
        component: ProductSelectionComponent
      },
      {
        path: "investor-detail",
        component: InvestorDetailComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EnterTransactionRoutingModule {}
```

HTML structure

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

layout.component.html

```
<app-cxi-layout-header></app-cxi-layout-header>
<app-cxi-layout-sidemenu></app-cxi-layout-sidemenu>
<app-cxi-layout-content></app-cxi-layout-content>
```

cxi-layout-content.component.html

```
<div class="cxi-layout-outer-body ">
  <div class="cxi-layout-inner-body flex content-center">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

enter-transaction.component.html

```
<h1>Enter-transaction > &&</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

product-selection.component.html

```
<p>product-selection works!</p>
```

I am using angular 8.
If I don't use lazy loading. it will works fine. But if I use lazy loading the enter-transaction module. it tells me cannot match nay routes.
I would expect that I can see the content of product-selection component in the right route.

Comment: Fixed, because I didn't declare all these components inside Enter-transaction module..

Comment: Also I made some change on the enter-transaction routing. the default routing should be "" not "enter-transaction"

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer. I'm stuck with the same issue, but have tried the fixes you mentioned without success.